# How do I call my function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I can not figure out how to call the function, `yea()`.

Here is my code, currently:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var myDate = new Date();

    function yea(){
      var year = myDate.getFullYear();
      for(var i = 1950; i < year+1; i++){
        return '<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>';
      }
    }

    $(wrapper).append(
      <div class="form-group">
        <select name="from_year[]" class ="form-control"> '+yea()+' </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
</script>
```

Comment: at least take the time to properly format the code in your question

Comment: Also, the reason it's not calling is because your call to `yea()` is inside of a string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript/6247331#6247331

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is not how you call `yea`, it is everything around it.

This would be fine:

```
append( some_string + yea() + some_string );
```

… but where you should have strings (which could be string literals or variables or any other JavaScript expression), you have *raw HTML*, which isn't allowed.

You seem to have missed the `'` off from the start of the first string, and the other `'` from the end of the second string, and inserted a raw new line in the middle of both (which is forbidden).

```
$(wrapper).append(
 '<div class="form-group"><select name="from_year[]" class ="form-control"> ' + yea() + ' </select></div>'
);
```